# Extract list of data from collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of collection like the following in mongodb

```
   { _id: ObjectId("6087feeef467a4320883daf3"),
     name: 'group 1',
     admins: ['adam', 'ken']
   }

   { _id: ObjectId("2087feeef467a4320883daf3"),
     name: 'group 2',
     admins: ['rebecca']
   }

   { _id: ObjectId("9987feeef467a4320883daf3"),
     name: 'group 3',
     admins: []
   }
```

I need to extract out all the admins, the end result would be something like this:

```
[
  'admin',
  'ken',
  'rebecca'
]
```

How can i do that, i stuck at this part:

```
db.data.find({ admins: { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} } })
```

This will show all collections, but i just need the list

Comment: You can write an aggregation query by unwinding (`$unwind`) the `admins`  and then grouping (`$group`) all documents to `$addToSet`  the admins field to an array field.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing so using single query is `unwinding` the array of admins and `adding them to a new set`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$admins"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      adminsSet: {
        $addToSet: "$admins"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The end result will be the following so you could extract your flattened array:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "adminsSet": [
      "ken",
      "rebecca",
      "adam"
    ]
  }
]
```

Mongo playground ref: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LFYsqHdTucN

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
db.data.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$admins"},
  {$project:{_id:0}}
]).map(x => x.admins);
```

Result

```
[
    "adam",
    "ken",
    "rebecca"
]
```

[image]